# How can I always see the last 30 days in Timesheets?

Tags: jira, time-management

We use Tempo timesheets to efficiently log work and see logged work.

I like the "last 30 days" view, as I can use it to easily log work on tasks I worked on before. The problem is, this only sets a fixed date, eg today it sets it to `March 30, 2017 - April 28, 2017`, but when I log in tomorrow that will remain the same, thus excluding tomorrow. Which means I have to change it every day.

Is there a way that I can make this "last 30 days" dynamic?

Comment: Have you tried saving a bookmark removing the from and to dates in the URL? I am nearly sure the parameter span=30 does the magic, so you would only need to have the URL without those parameters (from and to dates).

Comment: @lnjuanj I tried it, will report back to you tomorrow whether it worked.

Comment: @lnjuanj Yes this works, if you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bookmark, removing the from and to dates in the URL.

Whenever you click on "last 30 days" on Tempo, the URL is updated with a "to" and "from" fields. Thus, if you use the generated link afterwards, it will keep those fields and re-use the dates.

Since the URL also has a parameter called "span=30" that marks the "last 30 days" span, you would only need to have the URL without those parameters (from and to dates).

Creating a bookmark removing those from:

```
http://myjiraserver/secure/TempoUserBoard!timesheet.jspa?userId=userxyz&filterIds=-1001&use-ISO8061-week-numbers=true&period=&periodType=FLEX&periodView=DATES&from=2017-05-02&to=2017-05-31&exact=&span=30
```

to this:

```
http://myjiraserver/secure/TempoUserBoard!timesheet.jspa?userId=userxyz&filterIds=-1001&use-ISO8061-week-numbers=true&period=&periodType=FLEX&periodView=DATES&exact=&span=30
```

would do the trick.